# Catch API result - Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin

i have this function in my shared project which i referenced to my new project. basically this function job is to fetch contact information from my api.

[GetContact() function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eh0Km.png)

i call it when i load my profile page and set the result object (contact) as my profile page bindingcontext.

[calling the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GAhG.png)

which i binded on my ui.

[ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79PsI.png)

my problem is, since fetching data on api is always async. my code execute and exit immediately even the result from api is not yet fetch. resulting into a null bindingcontext. is there any way that i can catch the api result and update my bindingcontext so that my be updated ui also?

Comment: please do NOT post code or errors as images.  Take the time to paste them into the body of your question and format them so that they are readable

Answer (score 0):

For the async BindingContext I use the following:

XAML:

```
<Label Text="{Binding Type}"
       TextColor="#142E5F"
       Margin="10,0,0,0" 
       Font="Bold, 15"/>
```

ViewModel:

```
public int _type;
public int Type
    {
        get => _type;
        set => SetProperty(ref _type, value);
    }
```

With the SetProperty, you can change the value in execution time. You just need to asign the result.

```
public override async void OnAppering()
        {
            base.OnAppering();
            Type = await APICall();
        }
```